# mysql autoincrement and rails4 :sql structure.sql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, schema, auto-increment

Got a rails4 app and a mysql (innodb).

The schema is stored as structure.sql (`config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`).

Every migration I run saves **auto-incremented** keys from my development database in `structure.sql`.

Any elegant way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new table you can create it with out an id and then add it manually

```
create_table(:table_name, :id => false) do |t|
  t.integer :id, :options => 'PRIMARY KEY'
end
```

if the table exist all ready you should be able to remove the index

```
remove_index :table_name, :id
```

I hope that this helps.
Happy Hacking